Getting an element in JSON-response using .check
My code (Java) for my Gatling test is as follows:
package computerdatabase;

import io.gatling.javaapi.core.ScenarioBuilder;
import io.gatling.javaapi.core.Simulation;
import io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpProtocolBuilder;

import java.time.Duration;

import static io.gatling.javaapi.core.CoreDsl.*;
import static io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.http;
import static io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.status;

public class ProductSimulation extends Simulation {

HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http.baseUrl("https://dummyjson.com")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
        .check(status().is(200));

ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("GetProducts")
        .exec(http("products").get("/products").body(StringBody("{}"))
                .check((jsonPath("$.*").saveAs("response"))))
        .exec(session -> {
            System.out.println(session.getString("response"));
            return session;
        });

{
    setUp(scn.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(1).during(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))).protocols(httpProtocol);
}
}

Now I obtain the entire response body, but I only want the first "title" as in "Essence Mascara Lash Princess" given the json response body below (the first part of it)
[{"id":1,"title":"Essence Mascara Lash Princess","description":".....

How can I save the "title" to a variable and oprint it like I do for the entire json response?

Okay, there are two ways.
The first - you can 'directly' define to extract the first element :
.check(jsonPath("$[0].title").saveAs("title")))

The second way - you can save all elements and then use the desired through Gatling EL:
.check(jsonPath("$..title").findAll.saveAs("titles")))

"${titles(1)}"


Did not work. be aware of the first sign in the response body is [. Maybe not use jsonpath at all?

@MagnusJensen Are you sure? I checked it with
https://jsonpath.com/
https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#
https://mockoon.com/tools/json-object-path-evaluator/
https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-path-evaluator.html

$.*[0]title works when using your link, but $[0].title does not. I tried it now.

https://ctrlv.link/dfMK

@Amerousful's answer is correct and the solutions he's provided are correct. If they don't work for you, it means that either your actual payload doesn't match the one you've provided here, or that you're using an old buggy version of Gatling. As of now, the latest version is 3.11.5. Moreover, you might want to using JMESPath instead of JsonPath, see https://docs.gatling.io/reference/script/core/checks/#jmespath

This however works:
.check(jsonPath("$.*[0].title").saveAs("title"))

